# openssl-nodejs always return error while generating key and CSR

Tags: javascript, node.js, openssl

I'm using openssl-nodejs package to use openssl commands to generate CSR and Private key.
We are successfully generating the CSR and Private key files with below code. However, it's always returning the error response.

```
async function generateCsr(){
let subject = '';
let password = 'DummyPassword';

subject = `/CN=y1212.website.com/OU=Dp-PD/O=Dummy org/L=mars/C=DJ/emailAddress=abcd@website.com`;

openssl(
    [
        'req',
        '-sha256',
        '-newkey',
        'rsa:2048',
        '-keyout',
        'y1212.website.com-privkey.pem',
        '-out',
        'y1212.website.com.csr',
        '-subj',
        `${subject}`,
        '-passout',
        `pass:${password}`
    ], function (err, buffer) {
            if (err) console.log('OpenSSL error: ' + err); // RETURNS ERROR DESPITE OF GENERATING CORRECT FIELS
            console.log("string", buffer.toString()); // THIS IS NULL
});
}

generateCsr();
```

Output:

```
OpenSSL process ends with code 0
OpenSSL error: Generating a 2048 bit RSA private key
writing new private key to 'openssl/y1212.website.com-privkey.pem'
```

Question: Why it is always returning the error despite of generating the correct CSR and Private keys. Due to this, we are unable to handle error handling. How can we resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I am also curious about this question.
After digging the `openssl`, I finally know the issue.

Messages to the users go on `stderr`. What goes to `stdout` is the result of the openssl command.

By default, unless you use `-in` or `-out`, openssl takes data in from `stdin` and writes data out on `stdout` (the result like a pem file).

For example, in a shell, we have the below script to decrypt a `key-enc.pem` file and output a decrypted file `key-dec.pem`.

```sh
openssl rsa -in key-enc.pem -output key-dec.pem -passin pass:123
```

And it is the same as

```sh
openssl rsa -passin pass:123 < key-enc.pem > key-dec.pem
```

As you can see, you don't want the messages to the user to end up in the output file `key-dec.pem` which is why they are issued on `stderr`.

Let's go back to our NodeJs implementation of the openssl to see a real live example.

The following js will do the same like above, the difference is we don't specify the output with `-output`, so NodeJs will take the output to `stdout` for us in the callback function.

```js
const child_process = require("child_process");
const password = "123";

child_process.exec(
    `openssl rsas -in key-enc.pem -passin pass:${password}`,
    (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
            return;
        }
        console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
        console.error(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
    }
);
```

If everything goes well, we can see the output as below:

```
stdout: 
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIICXAIBAAKBgQCqGKukO1De7shrT8ebHkTz2eplU9VQQSQzY1oZMVX8i1m5
WUTLPz2yLJIBQVdXqhMCQBGoiuSoSjafUhV7i1cEGpb88h5NBYZzWXGZ37sJ5QsW
+sJyoNde3xH8vdXhzU7eT82D6X/scw9RZz+/6rCJ4p0=
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

stderr: 
writing RSA key
```

You can see `stdout` is the output we want. Also, you can see `stderr` still output a message `writing RSA key` even there is no error. That's what I mean in the sentence above `you don't want the messages to the user to end up in the output`. That's why the message is directed to `stderr` even there is no error.

Now our issue is how do we distinguish if there is an error or not?

If there is an error in the command, for example, I change `rsa` to `rsas` like below.

```js
child_process.exec(
    `openssl rsas -in key-enc.pem -output key-dec.pem -passin pass:${password}`,
    (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
            return;
        }
        console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
        console.error(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
    }
);
```

The callback function will catch the error with `if (error)`.
The error output would be like below:

**Notes: DON't show your password in console like in the example.**

```
exec error: Error: Command failed: openssl rsas -in private-key-enc.pem -passin pass:123
Invalid command 'rsas'; type "help" for a list.
```

I checked the [source code](https://github.com/codevibess/openssl-nodejs/blob/master/src/index.js) of the library you use and found that it calls the `callback` function like below:

```js
const stdout = [];
const stderr = [];

openSSLProcess.stdout.on("data", data => {
    stdout.push(data);
});

openSSLProcess.stderr.on("data", data => {
    stderr.push(data);
});

openSSLProcess.on("close", code => {
    console.log(`OpenSSL process ends with code ${code}`);
    callback.call(null, stderr, stdout);
});
```

As you can see, `err` is always returned as an array from the `callback` function and there would be always some data inside because of the reason I mentioned above.

I recommend you just use the `child_process.exec()` instead of the library you are using now.

Comment: Hi @ikhvjs, It's working as expected. You are awesome. Thanks for taking so much time to debug and explaining easy solution. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @umehta, You are welcome, please take care of the password I console.log in the example, you should not log the password in the console.